# How to create list of lists from flat list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Is there a way to create a list of lists so that:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

And would it be possible to create the list of lists where the lists are of different sizes? For example:

```
l = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['g'], ['h', 'i']]
```

Comment: what's your logic behind constructing the new list?

Comment: @AJ123 I have provided a function allowing you to set custom chunk sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 . For a `multi-dimensioned list` of **defined inner list size** :

```
>>> inner_size = 3
>>> out = [ l[i:i+inner_size] for i in range(0, len(l), inner_size) ]
>>> out
=> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

2 . For a `multi-dimensioned list` of **random inner list size** (this is kind of chunky unfortunately) :

```
>>> import random
>>> i=0
>>> out = []
>>> while i<len(l): 
          left_out = len(l) - i 
          inner_size = random.randint(1,left_out) 
          out.append(l[i: i+inner_size]) 
          i += inner_size 

>>> out
=> [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a consistent chunk size `n`, you can do:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

n = 3
l2 = [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
l2
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Given split indexes (which you can easily generate from a list of chunk sizes), you can produce custom slices:

```
splits = [0, 2, 6, 7, 9]
l2 = [l[start:end] for start, end in zip(splits, splits[1:])]
l2
# [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['g'], ['h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, you can set your own chunk sizes in the variable `chunk_sizes` either as a list or tuple or an integer

```
def chunk_list(l,chunk_sizes):
    if isinstance(chunk_sizes,int):
        for i in range(0,len(l),chunk_sizes):
            yield l[i:i + chunk_sizes]
    else:
        start = 0
        for size in chunk_sizes:
            if start < len(l):
                yield l[start:start + size]
                start += size

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

# custom chunk_sizes list
chunk_sizes = [2,4,1,2]
print ([sl for sl in chunk_list(l,chunk_sizes)])
#prints [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['g'], ['h', 'i']]


# integer chunk_sizes
chunk_sizes = 3
print ([sl for sl in chunk_list(l,chunk_sizes)])
#prints [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```